# How to set the Search View for List view items which is displayed from Sqlite Database using SimpleCursorAdapter class

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite, simplecursoradapter

Hello every one i am new to android i displayed image view with text view in list view from Sqlite database with help of custom simplecursoradapter class and it is working fine.
now i want to set the search view for these listview displayed from sqlite how to add search box and query for search please post the complete code

my ImageCursorAdapter.java

```
public class ImageCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

private Cursor c;
private Context context;
byte[] image;

public ImageCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.c = c;
    this.context = context;
}

public View getView(int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = inView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_view__patients, null);
    }
    this.c.moveToPosition(pos);

 String firstName = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
   String lastName = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("Name"));
    image = this.c.getBlob(this.c.getColumnIndex("Image"));


ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.all_img);
if (image != null) {

    if (image.length > 0) {
        iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length));
    } else {
        iv.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    }
}
TextView fname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.db_id);
fname.setText(firstName);

TextView lname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name_id);
lname.setText(lastName);
return (v);


}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHelper db;

SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
EditText et;

Cursor row;
ListView lv;
ImageCursorAdapter adapter;

int[] xml_id;
String[] column;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    open();
    db.getReadableDatabase();
  db.getWritableDatabase();


    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV);


    int layoutstyle = R.layout.activity_view__patients;
    xml_id = new int[]{
            R.id.db_id,
            R.id.name_id,
            R.id.all_img
    };
    column = new String[]{
            "patients._id",
            "patients.Name",
            "patients.Image"

    };

    row = db.fetchAllData();

    adapter = new ImageCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), layoutstyle, row, column, xml_id);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

private void open() {
    sqLiteDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase(DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add edittext box above listview control.
and make sql query like below ..

```
    public List<MyTable> getSearchData(String value) {
    MyTable data = null;
    List<MyTable> myTableList=new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + "User" + " WHERE name=" + value;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        data = new MyTable();
        data.id = (c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id")));
        data.comment = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("comment")));
        data.itemId = (c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("item_id")));
        myTableList.add(data);
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return myTableList;
}
```

this method call when click on button or other click event..

```
getSearchData(edittext.getText().toString().trim());
```

Comment: and if want to filter the record in listview after enter value in search box then used filterable in adapter.

Comment: why don't you use addTextChangedListener for edit text box adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString()); and  adapter.setFilterQueryProvider() method

Answer (score 0):

Ok based upon your code here's a working example :-

First the DatabaseHelper class (named for my convenience) :-

```
public class SO49813098DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "patients";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TB_PATIENT = "patient";
    public static final String PATIENT_COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String PATIENT_COL_NAME = "patient_name";
    public static final String PATIENT_COL_IMAGE = "patient_image";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public SO49813098DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TB_PATIENT + "(" +
                PATIENT_COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                PATIENT_COL_NAME + " TEXT," +
                PATIENT_COL_IMAGE + " BLOB DEFAULT X'000000000000'" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crtsql);
    }

    public long addPatient(String patient_name) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(PATIENT_COL_NAME,patient_name);
        return mDB.insert(TB_PATIENT,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getPatients(String filter_name) {
        String whereclause = PATIENT_COL_NAME + " LIKE ?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{"%" + filter_name + "%"};
        return mDB.query(TB_PATIENT,
                null,
                whereclause,
                whereargs,
                null,
                null,
                PATIENT_COL_NAME
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

The ImageCursorAdpter :-

```
public class ImageCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private Cursor csr;
    private Context context;

    public ImageCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context,c,0);
        //csr = c;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context,
                        Cursor c,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.activity_view__patients,
                parent,
                false
        );
    }

    public View getView(int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getView(pos,inView,parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor csr) {
        TextView dbid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.db_id);
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_id);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.all_img);

        dbid.setText(String.valueOf(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(SO49813098DBHelper.PATIENT_COL_ID))));
        name.setText(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(SO49813098DBHelper.PATIENT_COL_NAME)));
        iv.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
    }
}
```

- Note this extends CursorAdapter rather than SimpleCursorAdapter
- The `bindView` method has been used rather than `getView` method for populating the views, as this is passed the cursor (one of the issues I believe you had was in regard to positioning the cursor).

The MainActivity :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Cursor patients;
    ListView patients_listview;
    EditText patients_filter;
    String filter;
    SO49813098DBHelper mDBHelper;
    ImageCursorAdapter ica;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SO49813098();
    }

    private void SO49813098() {

        // Sets the Databaehelper
        mDBHelper = new SO49813098DBHelper(this);
        // Add some data for testing
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase(),SO49813098DBHelper.TB_PATIENT) < 1) {
            mDBHelper.addPatient("Fred");
            mDBHelper.addPatient("Bert");
            mDBHelper.addPatient("Harry");
            mDBHelper.addPatient("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy white dog");
        }

        // Get the views according to their id's
        patients_listview = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.patients);
        patients_filter = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.filter);

        filter = ""; // Initially set filter to show all
        // get the Cursor
        patients = mDBHelper.getPatients(filter);
        // setup the Adapter
        ica = new ImageCursorAdapter(this, patients);
        // Apply the adapter to the listview
        patients_listview.setAdapter(ica);

        // Add TextWatcher to the Filter Edittext to invoke the SO49813098RefreshList method
        patients_filter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                SO49813098RefreshList(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }

    // refresh the list by getting the Cursor according to the search
    // and then swapping the Cursor
    private void SO49813098RefreshList(String s) {
        patients = mDBHelper.getPatients(s);
        ica.swapCursor(patients);
    }
}
```

### Result

#### Initial :-

[image]

- Edit text highlighted

#### Type B (**B**ert and the quick **b**rown fox... are displayed)

[image]

#### Type r so now Br (just the quick **br**own fox ... is shown)

[image]